# How to make general Auth API for many microservices?

Tags: c#, spring-boot, asp.net-core, microservices, asp.net-core-3.1

I want to build General Auth API that serve like authorization service for many microservices. Actually I want to make the user authorization centralize. So microservices that have same collection of user doesn't have its own authorization.

The diagram that I want to implement is like this image below.
[image: my architecture what I want to implement]

Basically, user needs login/register in application. And then the microservices forward payload to general API. The general API, then, gives result of authentication and if the result exist microservices do the request that user gives.

Or you can suggest me some simple and reliable ways if this approach is too way complex,

btw I want to use .NET CORE to build this.

thanks

Comment: In general, I would think your Auth API would use some Authentication mechanism such as Identity library & Microsoft.Owin with cookie authentication. I would think your microservices can do an http request to the auth API to get authorization, and cache the results. then return the result to the user apps.

Comment: you need to use something such as Identity Server